# android + universal image loader : show custom marker with image in google map

Tags: android, image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bitmap

I am working on an application that has google map in it. The default marker in the map is visible but what i have to do is to get a image from the facebook url and then show it on the google map. I am using "universal-image-loader-sample-1.8.6.apk" to load the images using the url. 
Now to load a image i am doing this.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader;
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
ImageLoaderConfiguration ilc = ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
imageLoader.init(ilc);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.friend_pic);
imageLoader.displayImage(stringImageUrl, imageView);
```

The code is simple the **displayImage()** accepts two argument ,first is **stringImageUrl** *(the url of the pic)* second is **imageView** *(ImageView object in the layout)*.
Now why i need the ViewImage object if i have to show image on map.Well ImageLoader object does not returns bitmap image from any of its function to first i used the ImageView to set the fetched image from url to imageview and then get the image in Bitmap.

What i did is something like this.

```
Drawable drawble = imageView.getDrawable();
BitmapDescriptor icon=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)drawble).getBitmap());
```

Once i got the image in the BitmapDescriptor , its easy to set it in marker.

```
Marker location = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().visible(true)
                .title(stringName).position(position).icon(icon);
```

but the problem is , THIS IS NOT WORKING.Image is coming in **imageView** object but not able to get it to **Marker**.

Comment: Doesn't look like Universal Image Loader is universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that jar file from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

```
AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

Using above code you can directly show your Image through url. Now below code is to get Bitmap Directly from the url:

```
androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, object, status);

                            //You will get Bitmap from object.
                        }

                    });
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like Animation when loading; getting a bitmap, if needed; etc.

Comment: accept the answer if you found this useful, so other people can use it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

1.Download Latest AndroidQuery jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

2.Put this jar to your libs folder and right click on jar and Build Path -> Add to bulid path.

3.How to use see this example:

```
AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this);

androidQuery.ajax(url.trim(), Bitmap.class, 0, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
     @Override
     public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
         super.callback(url, object, status);
         googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("yourtitle").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(object)).position(new LatLng(yourlatitude), Double.parseDouble(yourlongitude))));
     }
});
```

Comment: it shows error AjaxStatus cannot be resolved to a type