# Retrieving bitmap image from a URL ,getting nullpointerexception randomly in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

Working on a project with google maps in it.I am trying to retrieve bitmap images from a URL and it works fine ,**but not all the time**

The code i am using to retrieve the url is inside a async class.

The async class:

```
public class retrieveimage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
    {
    Store_data s;
    MarkerOptions marker;
    Bitmap pinbit;
        public retrieveimage(Store_data s) {
            this.s=s;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                 marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s.store_latitude),Double.parseDouble(s.store_longitude))).title(s.store_name);
                String url1=arg0[0];
                URL url = new URL(url1);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                pinbit=bitmap;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return null;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            View custom_layout = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout,null);
            ImageView iv_category_logo=(ImageView) custom_layout.findViewById(R.id.iv_category_logo);
            pinbit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pinbit,68,62,false);
            iv_category_logo.setImageBitmap(pinbit);
            //pinbit=MainActivity.getCroppedBitmap(pinbit, 10);
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(StoreFinal.this, custom_layout)));
          // adding marker

          googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        }


    }
```

I am calling the async class as:

```
 new retrieveimage(sobj).execute(URL_image+sobj.category+".png");
```

The problem is that the variable `pinbit` gets NPE randomly.Many times the desired result is seen.But sometimes out of random i get NPE.So i think there is something wrong with the `doInBackground` method where the web operation takes place.How do i ensure that the code with the web operation doesnt break?

The LOGCAT:

```
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:344)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at com.igloo.storelocater.StoreFinal$retrieveimage.onPostExecute(StoreFinal.java:177)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at com.igloo.storelocater.StoreFinal$retrieveimage.onPostExecute(StoreFinal.java:1)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-18 18:26:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check out my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310985/android-universal-image-loader-show-custom-marker-with-image-in-google-map/19311091#19311091

Comment: first, you can prevent the NPE with `if(pinbit != null) { ... `. This will not call the NPE. But it seems either the host is not available or the background process is interrupted or something like that, therefore you need to retry this operation. The `AsyncHttpClient` library by loopj is perfect for this, it does all necessary operations and retries when it fails.

Comment: @Haresh , does it guarantee that the random NPE's will stop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try integrating AQuery library and use its callback method which will give you bitmap along with URL which it belongs. Hope it helps!