# Loading image in gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-asynctask

I have an activity with GridView element. GridView contains over 100 "cards", each card contains imageView . If image isn't presented in memory cache and disk cache starts asyncTask for loading image from web. If I scroll gridView fast and internet connection is slow I get such effect: images are being loaded and placed in that imageView by position on the screen, which was when the task was started. And so on, until the final image isn't loaded. 
Is it any solution to avoid such effect or, maybe, check if needed imageView is presented on the screen and cancel inserting if it is not?

Comment: Check my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310985/android-universal-image-loader-show-custom-marker-with-image-in-google-map/19311091#19311091

Comment: Use Picasso instend http://square.github.io/picasso/